# How do I get a combo box working in a nested function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently creating a temperature converter using Tkinter and python and I have a function which has a combo box in it.

When selecting Fahrenheit or Kelvin from the combo box, and inputting a number + clicking 'CONVERT' the temperatures that are displayed are that of Fahrenheit and Kelvin no matter what starting temperature you select.

This leads me to believe the combo box isn't recognizing the change and is always staying as 'Celsius'.

I have been adviced to use classes but am unsure of how to use so.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def tempConverter():
    temperatureConverter = Tk()
    temperatureConverter.geometry('650x650')


    dropDownBoxTempValue = "Celsius"

    def storedTemperature(setTemp):
        global dropDownBoxTempValue
        dropDownBoxTempValue = setTemp

    def convert():
        temperature = enterTemperature.get()
        if dropDownBoxTempValue == 'Celsius':
            f = (float(temperature) * 9 / 5) + 32
            temperatureLabel['text'] = f'{round(f, 2)}° Fahrenheit'
            k = (float(temperature)) + 273.15
            temperatureLabel2['text'] = f'{round(k, 2)}° Kelvin'

        elif dropDownBoxTempValue == 'Fahrenheit':
            c = (float(temperature) - 32) * 5 / 9
            temperatureLabel['text'] = f'{round(c, 2)}° Celsius'
            k = (float(temperature) - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15
            temperatureLabel2['text'] = f'{round(k, 2)}° Kelvin'

        elif dropDownBoxTempValue == 'Kelvin':
            c = (float(temperature) - 273.15)
            temperatureLabel['text'] = f'{round(c, 2)}° Celsius'
            f = (float(temperature) - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32
            temperatureLabel2['text'] = f'{round(f, 2)}° Fahrenheit'

    inputNumber = StringVar()
    variable = StringVar()

    enterTemperature = Entry(temperatureConverter, textvariable=inputNumber, font='Helvetica 14')
    enterTemperature.pack()
    temperatureLabel = Label(temperatureConverter, text="")
    temperatureLabel.pack()
    temperatureLabel2 = Label(temperatureConverter, text="")
    temperatureLabel2.pack()

    dropDownList = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]
    temperaturedropDown = OptionMenu(temperatureConverter, variable, *dropDownList, command=storedTemperature)
    temperaturedropDown.pack()
    variable.set(dropDownList[0])

    convertButton = Button(temperatureConverter, text="CONVERT", command=convert)
    convertButton.pack()

    temperatureConverter.mainloop()

tempConverter()
```

Comment: Isn't this an exact copy of the previous question you asked?

Comment: @BryanOakley, correct. I mean I need help like right now and thanks your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why not use `variable.get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the `dropdownBoxTempValue` never changes. It will only be `Celsius`. Therefore, you get only `Fahrenheit` and `kelvin` as output. Try printing `dropdownBoxTempValue`, you will find it out

And you do not need the function (or command) `storedTemperature` because it stores the temperature

Instead of that, get the value of `variable`, so that the code works -

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def tempConverter():
    temperatureConverter = Tk()
    temperatureConverter.geometry('650x650')


    dropDownBoxTempValue = "Celsius"
    
    def convert():
        temperature = enterTemperature.get()
        unit = variable.get() # Here
        #print(dropDownBoxTempValue) Try this
        
        if unit == 'Celsius':
            f = (float(temperature) * 9 / 5) + 32
            temperatureLabel['text'] = f'{round(f, 2)}° Fahrenheit'
            k = (float(temperature)) + 273.15
            temperatureLabel2['text'] = f'{round(k, 2)}° Kelvin'

        elif unit == 'Fahrenheit':
            c = (float(temperature) - 32) * 5 / 9
            temperatureLabel['text'] = f'{round(c, 2)}° Celsius'
            k = (float(temperature) - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15
            temperatureLabel2['text'] = f'{round(k, 2)}° Kelvin'

        elif unit == 'Kelvin':
            c = (float(temperature) - 273.15)
            temperatureLabel['text'] = f'{round(c, 2)}° Celsius'
            f = (float(temperature) - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32
            temperatureLabel2['text'] = f'{round(f, 2)}° Fahrenheit'

    inputNumber = StringVar()
    variable = StringVar()

    enterTemperature = Entry(temperatureConverter, textvariable=inputNumber, font='Helvetica 14')
    enterTemperature.pack()
    temperatureLabel = Label(temperatureConverter, text="")
    temperatureLabel.pack()
    temperatureLabel2 = Label(temperatureConverter, text="")
    temperatureLabel2.pack()

    dropDownList = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]
    temperaturedropDown = OptionMenu(temperatureConverter, variable, *dropDownList)
    temperaturedropDown.pack()
    variable.set(dropDownList[0])

    convertButton = Button(temperatureConverter, text="CONVERT", command=convert)
    convertButton.pack()

    temperatureConverter.mainloop()

tempConverter()
```

And you have used "huge"` variables names, it makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: thankyou!!!! I assumed that I needed a function to store the temperature... thank you for helping with that. I will be sure to change the variable names too!!